# spring boot 1.5.4 basic authentication REST API only jsession fails

Tags: rest, spring-boot, authorization, jsessionid

Am working with spring boot 1.5.4 and have a sringboot server basic authentication application.  The goal of the application is to login in with credentials and use the jsessionID received to verify authorization for each additional REST API calls made.

In my extended WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class my configure method is:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    log.info("In configure");

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        //    .antMatchers("/weather/getAll").hasAnyRole("ROLE_USER","ROLE_ADMIN")
            .and().csrf().disable()
            .logout()
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .permitAll();
}
```

Note: ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN are the granted authoritites I have defined in my user table.  Testing with curl and the following command works:

```
>curl -i -d "user=test1&password=test2" http://localhost:8080/user/login -c t1.txt
```

that is a 200 ok is returned along with a JSessionID.  I then attemt a call to get a specific weather record using curl as follows:

> curl -i -v   http://localhost:8080/weather/get/760 -b t1.txt 
>   Curl's output shows the JSessionID received on login being passed to the server application.  Always get a 403 status message returned.  The weather get method is as follows:

```
 @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
@GetMapping("get/{id}")
@JsonIgnore

public ResponseEntity<Weather> get(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){
    Weather weatherData = null;
    log.info("IN weatherTable get ");
    try{
        weatherData =  _weatherDao.getWeatherById(id);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("get Exception = "+e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Weather>(weatherData, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Reduced the complexity of the configure overridden method to try and troubleshoot the cause. Removing the Preauthorize annotation from the get method does return the expected record, so the backing code is correct.

Can't seem to find information/documentation that helps explain why the JSessionID value from login is not working for the authorization check.  Are there other steps needed?  Any debugging hints would be very appreciated.

EDIT
added this bit of code to help debug the issue:

```
// @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    @RequestMapping(value="/getAll")
    @JsonIgnore
    public  ResponseEntity<List<Weather>> getAll(){
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> ga = auth.getAuthorities();
        for (GrantedAuthority granted : ga){
            log.info("AUTHORITY = "+granted.getAuthority());
        }
        List<Weather> weatherData = null;
        try{
            weatherData = _weatherDao.getAll();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("getAll Exception = "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Weather>>(weatherData,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I opened up the permissions for /weather/** to permitAll() and tested with a login for a user with ROLE_USER.  Then called /weather/getAll using the cookie returned via curl (see above).  The log shows that the granted authority for this call is "ROLE_ANONYMOUS".

Looks like I'm missing something to allow the jsessionid to be tracked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `ROLE_` from the [authorization rule?](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-expressions-basic)

> Spring Security 4 automatically prefixes any role with ROLE_.

Seems to me that when Spring Security tries to match your role it finds nothing and you get this 403 error.

EDIT

Just to make it clear, my suggestion is to leave your configuration rule like this:

```
antMatchers("/weather/getAll").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
```

And keep your data in database like you have it now.

EDIT2:

There's a difference between `hasAnyRole` and `hasAnyAuthority`. Quoting from [this blog](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-expressions):

> Roles and authorities are similar in Spring.
>
> The main difference is that, roles have special semantics – starting with Spring Security 4, the ‘ROLE_‘ prefix is automatically added (if it’s not already there) by any role related method.
>
> So `hasAuthority(‘ROLE_ADMIN’)` is similar to `hasRole(‘ADMIN’)` because the ‘ROLE_‘ prefix gets added automatically.

That's why I asked you to remove the `ROLE_` prefix from your rule.

EDIT 3:

Now I saw that your request is `http://localhost:8080/weather/get/760`

So your rule should be like this:

`.antMatchers("/weather/get/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER","ROLE_ADMIN")`

Comment: using PreAuthorize("IsAuthenticated") for the rest method?  Are you recommending a DB modification to strip the ROLE from the granted authority value?

Comment: No! Just from the configuration on http.authorizeRequests()

Comment: Just registered a user with role of USER, logged in with that user getting a 200 ok and a jsessionid.  Then made the curl get call and received a 403 returned.  Will add some checks to verify the user information I'm working with.

Comment: Maintain your user as ROLE_USER at te database. Spring will take the USER from your rule, add the prefix and then will match.

Comment: tried both the .antmatcher approach and the PreAuthorize (removed when the .antmatcher was configured) still getting the 403.  Am thinking that is is a role mismatch.

Comment: Just edited my answer. I just saw your request. I think the problem is with your rule trying to match **/getAll** and your request is **/get/760**.